# Replacing a string in a file in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, sed

I am looking for a way to replace all occurrences of string A with B in a file.

I tried using GnuWin32 sed utility, but the result file is trimmed. It probably happens because the file contains non unicode characters. The same command worked on Mac with the same file only after adding LC_ALL=C before the command.
What other tools i can use and how? Can i pass some flag to GnuWin32 sed that will work with non unicode characters?

Comment: Why is this tagged with powershell?

Comment: I wonder if powershell can help in this task

Comment: What encoding the source file is?

Comment: @ErikSapir [I wonder if it can](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=powershell+replace+string+in+file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell something like this should work:

```
$f = 'C:\path\to\your.txt'
(Get-Content $f) -replace 'A','B' | Out-File $f
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use variable syntax:

```
${C:\path\to\your.txt} -replace 'A','B' | Out-File C:\path\to\your.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the files encoding it's impossible to tell if this will work but this uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

```
type "file.txt" |repl "A" "B" >"newfile.txt"
```